# I need a button to appear when not loged in and another when logged in, I need help fixing code PLEASE!

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, multisite

I want to make it so when user is logged out/in & viewing another user profile the only see the Contact Seller button & when user is logged in viewing their own profile it shows View Inbox & Edit My Profile buttons. Here is a screensoh that show a user logged in as admin viewing a profile belonging to flamez and seeing the incorrect buttons https://www.dropbox.com/s/lifcq06y54jol7z/Screenshot%20of%20error.png?dl=0

here is the code i have so far:

```
<style>
a.view_inbox_btn:link, a.view_inbox_btn:visited{
    background: Green;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 0px 9px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #457D2B;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 52px;}
a.view_inbox_btn:hover, a.view_inbox_btn:active {
    background-color: #4da64d;
}
a.edit_profile_btn:link, a.edit_profile_btn:visited{
    background: #ff7f00;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 0px 9px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #ff7f00;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    margin-top: 17px;}
a.edit_profile_btn:hover, a.edit_profile_btn:active {
    background-color: orange;
}
a.contact_seller_btn:link, a.contact_seller_btn:visited{
    background: Green;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 0px 9px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #457D2B;
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 52px;}
a.contact_seller_btn:hover, a.contact_seller_btn:active {
    background-color: #4da64d;
}
</style>    

<?php if (is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
<a href="http://enormu.com/marketplace/my-account/private-messages/"class="view_inbox_btn">View Inbox</a>
<a href="http://enormu.com/marketplace/my-account/personal-information/"class="edit_profile_btn">Edit Profile</a>
<?php else: ?> 
<a href="http://enormu.com/marketplace/my-account/private-messages/"class="contact_seller_btn">Contact Seller</a>
      <?php endif ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/245381/edit) to clarify the problem you're having (and any steps you've already taken to solve it).

Comment: sorry  i am new to the site.. just fiqure how the formating works.

Comment: Without telling us how profiles are implemented it's not possible to give an accurate answer

Comment: my code already works switching the buttons however if i am logged in as one user and viewing another user profile(not the current user profile page) i am seeing the view inbox & edit profile button instead of contact seller... i have also update the post with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the simplest way to achieve ( and perhaps not the better ) is to create a class 'btn-hidden' or similar, with display:none in the definition. Then, when you are in your template, control if user is logged in or not ( function is_user_logged_in() ) and if user is in one or other page ( depending on your configuration, this can be done in different ways, it could be by is_page('Page Name') function perhaps ). Finally, depending on the combination of these elements, apply the class to the buttons that should be hidden.

Hope this helps, but I think the question needs some more information about the context.

Comment: can you give an example of the code, my code already works switching the buttons however if i am logged in as one user and viewing another user profile(not the current user profile page) i am seeing the view inbox & edit profile button instead of contact seller... i have also update the post with a screenshot

Comment: You then should get the other user profile id, and compare that with logged in user id.

Comment: i dont understand, may i have an example of the code

Comment: Sorry, I cannot edit previous comment. The way you can do is to take the current profile from url ( if you cannot get the page user id in other better way ):

`code` 
$currentUserId = get_current_user_id();
$page_owner_id = $wpdb->get_var('

Comment: i am new at coding so that is why i asked for an example code... i will try to figure this out

Comment: I cannot understand why I'm not able to edit my own comments, I don't get the point. Sorry again, I will post another answer.

Comment: okay thank you, as for editing a comment you can only edit a comment for the 1st 3 minutes after it has been posted... after that the option to edit grays out

Comment: I cannot see you last comment

Comment: I've modified my other response with the same information, you can check the [edit] part to get the user nick from the url

Comment: i have not modified the site as yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_the_author_meta('id') if the page author is the user you need to compare. If not, perhaps get the nick from the url and search in database from its id.

```
$currentUserId = get_current_user_id();
$lastPartOfUrl = 'flamez'; // Get from the url, as in your screenshot
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'users';
$page_owner_id = $wpdb->get_var("select ID from $table where user_login='$lastPartOfUrl'");

//Then compare
if($currentUserId === $page_owner_id){
    //We show the edit profile button
}else{
    //We show the other button
}
```

Hope this helps to better understand.
TAKE CARE of cleaning your $lastPartOfUrl variable, as it will break your code or expose you to [SQL injection](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilsLiwp5fQAhWBg1QKHZBWBAgQFghAMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.acunetix.com%2Fwebsitesecurity%2Fsql-injection%2F&usg=AFQjCNGiZSsTeE0442VXvNvWodckCeh3fg&sig2=nB-T0cPk53Q4l0rdIDfQsA&bvm=bv.137904068,d.d2s).

[EDIT] If you do not know the last part of url, you can extract it like this:

```
$currentPage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$parts = explode('?',$currentPage); 
$lastPartOfUrl = basename(trim($parts[0],'/'));
```

Comment: Just in case $wpdb is not working, you can start this part wiht the sentence: global $wpdb, which is the database handler object of Wordpress

Comment: okay... and for $lastPartOfUrl = 'flamez'; can it be $lastPartOfUrl = '_'; because of the other users

Comment: I assumed you know that part of url inside the code, as I suppose you use it for showing or for other stuff. In case you do not have that variable data, you can extract it from the url parsing current url with something like this (not tested):

$currentPage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = explode('?',$currentPage);
$lastPartOfUrl = basename(trim($parts[0],'/'));

Comment: @G.Brown, the $lastPartOfUrl variable should contain the current page user's nick, I've added more information to my response so you can get that nick from the url, and then take his id from the database. That way you can say if the user is the current user or not comparing the ids.

Comment: Did this worked for you, @G.Brown ?